# Checking If Then statements in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

When I write an if statement, I have it check a variable like so:

```
if(isset($_GET['username']){
 echo "set";
 } else {
 echo "unset";
}
```

How could I get my if statement to check if two variables are set similiar to this:

```
if(isset($_GET['username'] & $_GET['firstname'])){
 echo "set";
 } else {
 echo "unset";
}
```

So basically how do I check two things in an if statement at once?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Albeit this is a pretty basic question, but people need to learn this stuff somewhere, and this is as good a place as any. Sure, it might not hurt to get an introductory programming book, but be kind to the noobs.

Answer (score 11):

Check out the PHP Manual on [control structures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) and [logical operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php):

```
if(isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['firstname'])) {
    echo "set";
} else {
    echo "unset";
}
```

Using the single `&` is doing a [bitwise operation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php), which is most certainly not what you want.

`and` is also a synonym to the `&&` syntax, as the other answers have shown.

**EDIT**: As pointed out in the comments, you can check if two variables are isset by passing them  both to the isset function. However, if you ever wanted to do some other sort of operation you would need to do the logical operators above.

Comment: Take a look at Nick Presta's answer.

Comment: I was answering the general question of "So basically how do I check two things in an if statement at once?" but I guess I'll edit my answer to include that...

Answer (score 7):

```
if ( isset($_GET['username'], $_GET['firstname']) ) {
    echo 'Set!';
}
```

[isset](http://php.net/isset) takes multiple arguments and if multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered.

Comment: Yeah I was about to say this myself. I can't believe all the other answers which didn't pick up on this...

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['firstname']) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the && operator (logical and) rather than & (binary and)

so if isset returns true for both then the if returns true otherwise the if will return false.

Answer (score 1):

yes, or

echo ( (isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['firstname'])) ? "set" : "unset" );

Comment: I tend to like something like this best.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_GET['username']) AND isset($_GET['firstname']))
{
    echo "set";
}
else
{
    echo "unset";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['firstname']))
{ 
    echo "set"; 
} 
else 
{ 
    echo "unset"; 
}
```

For reference: [PHP's operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php)

Comment: uh, is that correct? i don't think so. if it is, is some ugly php-hack again ... "($_GET[] && $_GET[])" evaluates to a boolean value. variables can be set or not, values just ... are.

Comment: You are missing an apostrophe after 'username'.

Furthermore, that is not valid code at all.

Comment: Fixed the code to be the way I originally meant it. I copied the question code changing their use & (the incorrect operator) for && without checking the rest of it.